# Regex practice from Learning Perl

Tags: regex, perl

While reading *Learning Perl*, I came across a problem about regular expressions. In Chapter 9, exercise 3 asks the student to use regex to replace a string a with another string b and replace b with a, e.g.:
if a='hitman' and b='assassin', then 'A hitman murdered an assassin' should be modified to 'A assassin murdered an hitman'.

In the book the answer is to delete all the eoln and then use eoln as a place holder to deal with this situation, but this method seems to be clumsy and is not universally applicable. Maybe someone could have a better, e.g., a one-liner, to solve this one?

Comment: ›delete all the **eoln** and then use eoln as a place holder‹, what's an "eoln"?

Comment: @knittl end of line. I wrote Pascal years ago:)

Comment: EOL makes sense, but there are no EOLs (linebreaks?) in your example

Comment: Don’t forget to swap around the *a* and *an*, or it won’t sound right.

Comment: @tchrist Not my fault - the regex won't do it if this is done properly:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
s/(hitman|assasin)(.+)(hitman|assasin)/$3$2$1/;
```

Or using the /e modifier:

```
s/(hitman|assasin)/$1 eq 'hitman' ? 'assasin' : 'hitman'/eg;
```

That second example detects whether hitman was found.  If so, substitute 'assasin'.  If not, substitute 'hitman'.

Comment: The `/eg` version is great, except for the spelling.

Answer (score -1):

Very specific, but would probably work for this case (given that there is only one instance each and ›hitman‹ comes before ›assassin‹):

```
s/^(.*)hitman(.*)assassin(.*)$/$1assassin$2hitman$3/
```

or even

```
s/^(.*)(hitman)(.*)(assassin)(.*)$/$1$4$3$2$5/
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The example only serves as an explanation in my post, but thank you nonetheless. Could you give a more general approach?

Comment: i'm afraid not, that's why i mentioned it's very specific to this question … sorry

Comment: Thank you all the same for the reply! Maybe this problem is theoretically not doable?

Comment: What’s in `$$2`? :_ Or rather, what is in `$hitman`, since that’s what `$$2` here evaluates to. :(

Comment: @tchrist: sorry man, my keyboard swallowed a keypress. should be `$3$2` – updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

I would check for the beginning and end of word anchors.

```
's/\<\([Aa]ssassin\)\>\(.*\)\<\([Hh]itman\)\>/\3\2\1/'
```

spread out is: s/ \< ( [Aa]ssassin ) > (.*) \< ( [Hh]itman ) >   /   \3 \2 \1    /

the \< and > is to make sure the word is on its own. The ( and ) is to save assassin, the text in between, and hitman to 1, 2, and 3 respectively.